# Using a variable in a PHP echo function

Tags: php, variables

I'm have a set of XML attributes with specific IDs to separate their child content, like so:

```
<attribute id="1">
    <childattribute1></childattribute1>
    <childattribute2></childattribute2>
</attribute>
<attribute id="2">
    <childattribute1></childattribute1>
    <childattribute2></childattribute2>
</attribute>
```

The ID variables match a URL parameter, which I'm grabbing and storing as a variable like this:

```
$franchiseID = $_GET['franchise'];
```

The result is just a matching number, such as:

```
$franchiseID = 1 (or 2, or 3, or whatever)
```

I'm trying to use that variable in an echo call, so that only the child attribute of the parent attribute with that specific ID is called:

```
<?php echo $franchise->popups->franchisepop->franchiseTitle[$franchiseID]->franchisetitle ?>
```

But this doesn't work.  What's the proper syntax for using a variable like this?

Comment: Well what does `$franchise` look like?

Comment: Its just the root of the XML call.  Its defined in the PHP file as  $franchise = simplexml_load_file('franchise.xml');

Comment: They mean maybe a `print_r()`?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you're asking?  Forgive my lacking PHP knowledge.

Comment: make `var_dump($franchise);` and see what you have in the variable

Comment: If you can, put output in question

Comment: Show your actual XML so we can see how all the elements are nested.

Comment: If `$franchiseID` is in an `id="xxx"` attribute, you need to use the `find()` method to find it, you can't use it as an array index.

Comment: Ah, so I can't use a variable as an array index at all?

Comment: Yes, but how do you know `franchiseTitle` is an array?

Comment: I don't think I've explained the issue very well.  There are a lot of parts, and I just need the answer to the last part, which is how to use the literal value of a variable inside an array index (IE $attribute[$variable])  But, there's another way to do it, so I'm going to swap strategies.  Thanks for the help everyone.  My bad for not being able to present the issue clearly.